# How To Read Per Specific Word With Scanner Java?

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

Hello I Have Filename save, for save game in My Java program. And this file like this

```
=
B
.
.
.
.
.
W
.
B
.
W
.
B
.
.
.
B
W
W
B
.
.
.
.
.
==
1
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
1
0
1
0
1
0
0
0
1
1
1
1
0
0
0
0
0
===
9
====
2
=====
5
```

I'm confused, how to read this file, and store value of this file per specific into 2D array and other variable,
currently i have 5 variable

```
arrMove[5][5], arrProc[5][5], forTurn, seconds, totalSeconds
```

i have this code for loadgame, and currently just 1 array that i can store from this file
and that's with error

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
Scanner inFile1 = new Scanner(new File("save.txt"));
while (inFile1.hasNext()) {
// find next line
    if (inFile1.hasNext("=")){
        ActivityBoard.arrMove[x][y] = inFile1.next();
        y++;
        if (y > 4) {
            y = 0;
            x++;
        }
    }
}
inFile1.close();
```

and this is my savegame

```
if (e.getSource().equals(SaveMenu)) {
            try {
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("save.txt");
                out.println("=");
                for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                        out.println(ActivityBoard.arrMove[i][j]);
                    }
                }
                out.println("==");
                for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                        out.println(ActivityBoard.arrProc[i][j]);
                    }
                }
                out.println("===");
                out.println(forTurn);
                out.println("====");
                out.println(seconds);
                out.println("=====");
                out.println(TotalTimer.getTime());
                out.close();
                this.dispose();
                System.exit(1);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ActivityBoard.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
```

i want store this value to my variable

from delimiter `=` to `==`
i want store into array `arrMove[5][5]`

from delimiter `==` to `===`
i want store into array `arrProc[5][5]`

from delimiter `===` to `====`
i want store into `forTurn`

from delimiter `====` 
i want store into `seconds`

can anyone help me ? thanks :)
sry for my bad english.

Comment: Did you store that file or are you working on a third party format?

Comment: i'm store that file sir, in my program

Comment: A state machine could help, but I guess, this is to "heavy" for someone new. If this is your file, then try to find a better file format, that makes it easier to read again.

Comment: could you suggest me better format for store into file sir, i'm confuse, i'm new to java, and from google i just have this code for save and load

Comment: A `BufferedReader` with `readLine()` is easier than `Scanner`. It looks like diagram as represented, diagram with points and a bit more.

Comment: ok sir, thanks for the advice, i will try again later with that, thank you very much for all of your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a great file format, but it would be pretty easy to parse like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String s;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("c:/temp/x.txt"));
    while( ! "=".equals((s = scanner.next()))) {
        // Ignore - getting to start
    }

    while( ! "==".equals((s = scanner.next()))) {
        // Put in first array
        System.out.println("First section: " + s);
    }

    while( ! "===".equals((s = scanner.next()))) {
        // Put in first array
        System.out.println("Second section: " + s);
    }

    // etc...
}
```

Comment: wow, that's working thank you sir, i'm spending 3 hours to solve this, with banging my head into wall, you solve this just within minute :D, a very much thanks sir :*